# Integrate existing Git Repository with Perforce (P4)

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I have browsed through the web, but I cannot find an answer.
What I am trying to do is the following:

1. I have a git repository which has been used for over 1 year with lots of commits
2. Due to productization, the code has to be moved into a P4 rep.
3. However, the codebase (after transport) may change in git as well as P4

Now lets assume that reference branch in git is *master*

What I did is the following:

1. Copy the latest code from git into P4 and submit it there
2. Use git-p4 sync --branch=refs/remotes/p4/masterp4 //../ in order to create a new branch in my existing repository
3. git merge *master* into *masterp4*
4. does not work since a common commit is missing
5. git-p4 submit, moreover, is not able to work with merge commits anyway

Another option was rebasing

1. Start with an empty repository in P4
2. Use git-p4 sync to create an empty *masterp4* branch in git
3. Rebase *master* onto *masterp4*
4. Rebase *masterp4* onto *remote/p4/master*
5. Leads to thousands of p4 changelists.

The main problem is the broken link between the master branch and this masterp4 branch.
I wondered if there is not an easier solution anyway. Unfortunately, I am a git n00b.

Thanks for any ideas,

Philipp

Comment: Perforce just came out with Perforce Git Fusion. http://www.perforce.com/git-fusion

Comment: thx Daniel, I am aware of that but some colleagues told me that it hasn't worked well in their environment either. However, they didn't try git-p4. Otherwise I really believe that there is a solution for that.

Comment: Can you do the merge with --no-ff to create a single commit?

Comment: This blog might provide some food for thought: http://www.perforce.com/blog/121030/git-fusion-working-open-source.  It uses a staging repository as a way to reconcile the data, since both Git Fusion and git-p4 have some limitations.  (Git Fusion will support merge commits early next year.)

Comment: Maybe --squash on the git merge command might help? That should create a single commit with the same effect as merging the branch. (Loses history though).

Comment: I guess an additional question might be why you don't want 1000s of perforce commits - that way you preserve your history of the project?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with creating 1000s of Perforce commits, so that history is preserved.